# How to Subset Text File in Python Using Grouping?

Tags: python

I am just starting out in python. I am unable to solve the following problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
> #code1 information about code here abcdefghijklmnopqrst  information line continures #code2 information about code here xyz #code3
> information about code here klm #code4 details found here, information
> {}}} information and details continued #code5....
```

I want my output to be 2 txt files. one with all lines pertaining to code1 and 1 with all lines pertaining to code4.

```
   with open("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\Codes.txt","r") as f:
    d = {}


    for line in f:
        start = "#code"

    code,number  = line.strip().split(start)
    if d.has_key(number):
        d[number].append(code)

    else:
        d[number] = []
        d[number].append(code)


for key,value in d.iteritems():
    f = open("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\New folder\{}.txt".format(number), "w")
for item in value:    
    f.write("{}\n".format(item))
    f.close()
```

I am not sure how to (1) group all lines pertaining to codes that bleed over to a new line and (2) how to select only the two codes (code1 and code4) to write to new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do something like this:

```
import re
code_dict = dict()

f = open("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\Codes.txt","r")
code = f.read()
f.close()

code_to_retain = ['#code1', '#code4']
key_word = None
for word in code.split(' '):
    if word in code_to_retain:
        code_dict[word] = list()
        key_word = word
        continue
    elif re.search('#code\d+', word):
        key_word = None
        continue

    if key_word:
        code_dict[key_word].append(word)

for key_word in code_dict.keys():
    lines = ' '.join(code_dict[key_word])

    #f = open("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\New folder\{}.txt".format(key_word.replace('#', '')), "w")
    f = open('/tmp/{}.txt'.format(key_word.replace('#', '')), "w")
    f.write(lines)
    f.close()
```

Output:

cat /tmp/code1.txt:

```
information about code here abcdefghijklmnopqrst  information line continures
```

cat /tmp/code4.txt:

```
details found here, information
> {}}} information and details continued
```

Comment: This solution works best for me! I ended up using re.match instead re.search. However, both work for me now.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to write directly to the output files, instead of creating interim lists and dictionaries.

You also want to make sure to strip out the random line breaks while you do so.

I made a file with several copies of your text above, and tested it with this code:

```
#output for items labeled "#code1"
code1out = open('code1.txt', 'w')
#output for items labeled "#code4"
code4out = open('code4.txt', 'w')
#open our codes.txt file
with open('codes.txt') as f:
    #create a list of strings that splits on the hash/pound symbol
    lines = f.read().split('#')
    #iterate through our list of codes
    for item in lines:
        #get rid of line breaks in our list
        item = item.replace('\n', '')
        #split each item after the first word (i.e., "code1", "code2", followed by the rest of the string)
        wholelinesplit = item.split(' ', 1)
        #check if the first word is "code1" or "code4", and if so, print to the appropriate file, with a line break at the end of the string
        if wholelinesplit[0] == 'code1':
            code1out.write(wholelinesplit[1] + '\n')
        elif wholelinesplit[0] == 'code4':
            code4out.write(wholelinesplit[1] + '\n')
```

Here's the output in code1.txt:

```
information about code here abcdefghijklmnopqrst  information line continures 
information about code here abcdefghijklmnopqrst  information line continures 
information about code here abcdefghijklmnopqrst  information line continures 
information about code here abcdefghijklmnopqrst  information line continures
```

Here's the output in code4.text:

```
details found here, information> {}}} information and details continued 
details found here, information> {}}} information and details continued 
details found here, information> {}}} information and details continued 
details found here, information> {}}} information and details continued
```